# What doesn't e.upcase return upper case words

Tags: ruby, arrays

I wanted to upper-case an array but got this behaviour:

```
=> ["this", "set", "of", "words", "is", "in", "a", "certain", "order"]
```

for this:

```
%w[this set of words is in a certain order].each {|e| e.upcase}
```

Why were the words NOT upper-cased?

(ignoring actual ordering right now dessite the words while I resolve this issue).

Answer (score 1):

[`String#upcase`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-upcase) returns a new string value, it doesn't modify the receiver.  Use [`String#upcase!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-upcase-21) to get the behavior you want, or use map to produce a new array of the upcased values.

```
%w[this set of words is in a certain order].each { |e| e.upcase! }

up_words = %w[this set of words is in a certain order].map(&:upcase)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
irb> %w[this set of words is in a certain order].map {|e| e.upcase}
=> ["THIS", "SET", "OF", "WORDS", "IS", "IN", "A", "CERTAIN", "ORDER"]
```

`each` throws away all the results, `map` collects all the results in a new array for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mutating the input array. Although each is actually upcased while iterating, the original array will be returned unchanged. Use `upcase!` instead:

```
# Modifies the array in place and returns the modified version:
>> %w[this set of words is in a certain order].each {|e| e.upcase!}
=> ["THIS", "SET", "OF", "WORDS", "IS", "IN", "A", "CERTAIN", "ORDER"]

# Assign it to a variable to get the up-cased array:
up_cased = %w[this set of words is in a certain order].each {|e| e.upcase!}
up_cased
# => ["THIS", "SET", "OF", "WORDS", "IS", "IN", "A", "CERTAIN", "ORDER"]
```

If you were to print them in the `each`, they would have been upcased, but the original unmutated array was returned.

```
# Calls upcase for proof, but the original array is still returned:
>> %w[this set of words is in a certain order].each {|e| puts e.upcase}
THIS
SET
OF
WORDS
IS
IN
A
CERTAIN
ORDER
=> ["this", "set", "of", "words", "is", "in", "a", "certain", "order"]
```

It is a little easier to see if you operate on a variable:

```
arr = %w[this set of words is in a certain order]
# upcase, but don't modify original
arr.each {|e| e.upcase}
arr.inspect
# ["this", "set", "of", "words", "is", "in", "a", "certain", "order"]

# now modify in place with upcase!
arr.each {|e| e.upcase!}
arr.inspect
# ["THIS", "SET", "OF", "WORDS", "IS", "IN", "A", "CERTAIN", "ORDER"]
```